# Spring MVC Template Location

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring boot stores in template files in /src/main/resources

Where is this configured and how can I get Spring MVC to do this when not using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Boot templating is usually configured via autoconfiguration, which takes information from application properties. For instance Thymeleaf template location can be configured like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.
```

See [Spring Boot properties reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for more details.

Without using Spring Boot you can configure the same behavior by specifying custom `ViewResolver` bean and specifying prefix for templates. You can take a look at [`ThymeleafAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) for inspiration.

Same principles apply to using other templating engines than Thymeleaf with Spring MVC.

Comment: How do you know what spring boot is using by default? This is why I don't like spring boot.

Comment: @DD. Documentation/looking through code. I personally love Spring Boot. It has defaults (which are typically very reasonable), it is well documented and if something doesn't suit you you can easily override it. In most situation I don't need to override a lot, resulting in a project where I can focus on the business concerns instead of writing infrastructure code all my time.